# default camera setting in chrome, used on macbook pro to video chat through facebook messenger not respected

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macbook-pro, webcam, facebook-chat

As per the title, I have an external webcam (logitech brio) attached and set as default in chrome. It works fine in other sites like google chat. however, Facebook Messenger always defaults to the built-in camera on the MacBook.

I am looking for a way to use Facebook Messenger on Chrome with the external camera. messenger not using the external camera is the issue.

Comment: That it defaults to is no problem as long as it lets you change the settings. And it should at least when in a call.

Comment: It don’t let me papa